# Value simple chooser option as a sum of call and put options

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes

There is a well known formula for valuating the chooser's option price:
$H_{chooser}=max\{C(S_t, K, T-t), P(S_t, K, T-t)\}=max\{C(S_t, K, T-t), C(S_t, K, T-t)+Ke^{−r(T-t)}−S_t\}=C(S_t, K, T-t) + max\{0, Ke^{−r(T-t)}−S_t\}$

The max element of this formula resembles the regular European put option, so is it correct to rewrite the formula as a sum of a call and put options?

$H_{chooser}=C(S_t, K, T-t)+P(S_t, Ke^{−r(T-t)}, T-t)$

Comment: Iff you have the flexibility to chose right up to expiry, then as you've written the value is the same as for a straddle. If you have to choose earlier, then it's a bit more complex.

Comment: Please have look of [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21975/how-to-price-an-option-allowing-to-change-a-call-into-a-put/21978#21978).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but you will need to account for two times:  decision time and the option maturities, lets call them $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$. The put call parity that you used relates prices of the options as at decision time  $\tau_1$ for resdiual maturities $\tau_2 -\tau_1$. So when you take the call price out of the max, it has payoff at $\tau_2$. The other term becomes $ max \left( 0, -S+K e^{-r(\tau_2-\tau_1)}\right)$ which is a put option with maturity $\tau_1$ and strike $K e^{-r(\tau_2-\tau_1)}$.

So in summary you can write it as sum of a call and a put option but the options have different maturities and different strikes.

Comment: I didn't mention it but one of the conditions is that both call and put options should have the same strike and expire at the same time.

Comment: If I see it correct the options that consist the chooser option are actually virtual, they have the same strike and I can decide which one of them to take up to the specific time. On the other hand the real options in straddle have different strikes and I can decide which one of them to take up to the their expiration.

Comment: I think of it this way: In straddle you have both options until $\tau_2$. In chooser option, you have to give up one of them at $\tau_1$ and hence the difference. Glass half-full/half-empty kinda situation!